# Multiple languages in doxygen docs (C++)

Tags: documentation, doxygen, multilingual

My client gave me unusual (and non-negotiable) requirement to provide them with dual-language (English and Polish) doxygen documentation from C++ code.

My first idea is to use conditional compilation for comments, like:

```
#if DOXYGEN_ENGLISH
/**
 * @brief Sample method
 */
#elif DOXYGEN_POLISH
/**
 * @brief Przykładowa metoda
 */
#endif
void foo();
```

Then run Doxygen twice with different base locale and predefined constant... and it actually works. But it's very cumbersome...

Have someone has an idea how can I improve this solution? Or solve it different way?

Comment: This solution seems good already, this is what I would do in this case.

Comment: did you have  a look at \~[laguageid] ? It still requires but twice the generation but uses build in commands from doxygen.

Comment: @albert That's great! Can you post this as answer so I can accept this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doxygen has the build in command \~[langId] for handling different languages.
The above presented example could be formulated as:

```
/**
 * \~english @brief Sample method
 * \~polish @brief Przykladowa metoda
 */
void foo();
```

- no direct requirement using a preprocessor / pre-processor directives / settings
- only one place in the doxygen configuration file to be changed (Doxyfile) when switching language.

Comment: Is it possible to mix two languages: the main manual in English, and translation inserts in some local language (Russian) and get manual with mixed languages (with some styled translation parts)?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but you can write just the Russian text into the normal tags and still have the main manual in English. Doxygen does no translations, only for the fixed texts there is a mechanism that the texts are translated. When I missed something, open a new question (with small example).

Comment: all comments marked with \~polish will be switched off if Doxygen will be built with default English language, and in reverse all English-marked text will be disabled in Polish build, I need double language document with both languages be visible, but \~polish marked with font style or color

Comment: You want to have a document with a main language (English) and some sentences in another language (Polish), correct? As 2nd requirement you need  that the part in the other language is in another font / style. Are there any restrictions on the output formats (like HTML / LaTeX etc.) / is only one output format required? You can write just the text in the main language and the other language. Depending on the complexity one has to think on defining some layout commands by means of an ALIAS that can be placed around the other language. Please open a new question (with example) for this.

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov: According to the Doxygen manual: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdtilde
You could write your documentation with \~ as default, and then for the Russian specific parts mark them with \~russian.